Laravel .htaccess redirect non-www to www subdomain on nginx
as title says, trying to simply redirect all non-www requests to www.
Have tried a ton of solutions, nothing working. Current htaccess is below. Probably something simple.
Edit: for stupid reasons, I can't do this at the nginx level
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect non-www to www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^paulevanscoaching\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.paulevanscoaching.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


Since .htaccess is for Apache, it does nothing with nginx. Search for how to redirect with nginx.

What OS are you working with? what problem raise up after redirection? 404? or what?

Why you can't do this at the nginx level? In your .conf create 2 server blocks, first one for redirect, something like server_name www.yourdomain.com         return 301 $scheme://yourdomain.com$request_uri; and the second one something like server_name yourdomain.com with the rest of the configs
